# Sharepoint unit testing using fakes framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sharepoint, microsoft-fakes, sharepoint-clientobject

I have an application which uploads a file to SharePoint via client object model. Now I need to write unit test cases for this application. The problem is, I how do I write test cases for the scenarios when

1. a folder exists
2. a folder does not exist

since this scenario can change anytime i cannot hardcore a folder name. I need to use Microsoft fakes framework. But can I use shims? If so... how to use it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fakes would allow you to simulate a the physical file/folder access. There are plenty of articles/MSDN on how to do this using Shims Context. Without a specific code example you trying to write, it is harder to provide you with a specific solution.

Comment: @Spock, this is about *SharePoint* folders, not physical folders. The Client SDK provides a set of proxy classes and functionality over a REST API. To mock specific folders, you'd have to mock the relevant objects, the SDK method calls  or the server's responses.

Comment: Consider using nhibernate for SharePoint, http://blog.bendsoft.com/category/nhibernate-for-sharepoint/